# Auto pass or recieve a ForeignKey instance value

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, instance

Say I have a Profile Model that gets created automatically from auth.models.User by using signals and on the Profile model OneToOneField, I have a company attribute tied to a Company model by ForeignKey. Meanwhile this Company model gets created at signup too via Foreignkey using formset_factory in views. What I am aiming to achieve is having the Company instance created at signup passed to the Profile instance Foreignkey as well. Tried using signals, overiding save methods etc. doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a sample code, all suggestions are greatly appreciated in advance.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Company(models.Model):
    comp_admin = model.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    .............................
    .............................
    other attributes omitted
    .............................

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, literally, few minutes after asking this question, I figured it out. What I did was use post_save to update the company attribute, but checked if the Company instance had the same comp_admin attribute value as the user attribute value. I'm guessing overriding the **init** method will work as well, but seems a bit long.